# Kotlin Filtering a list of Objects to make sure at least 1 Workstation is covered

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I need to make sure all workstations are covered, so people can book time off, there are 4 workstations but people can only do 1 at a time. I need to ensure all Workstations have at least 1 person in to cover it, the issue I have with my code is that people are capable of multiple workstations

```
enum class WorkStations {
    PANEL, OUTSIDE, MOVEMENTS, EXTRUDER
}

data class Operator(val name: String, val workStations: List<WorkStations> = 
emptyList())

fun main() {

val array = arrayListOf(
    Operator(
        "Andy",
        listOf(WorkStations.PANEL, WorkStations.OUTSIDE, WorkStations.MOVEMENTS)
    ),
    Operator(
        "Alan",
        listOf(WorkStations.PANEL, WorkStations.OUTSIDE, WorkStations.MOVEMENTS)
    ),
    Operator(
        "Matt",
        listOf(WorkStations.OUTSIDE)
    ),
    Operator(
        "Paul",
        listOf(WorkStations.EXTRUDER, WorkStations.MOVEMENTS)
    ),
    Operator(
        "Jack",
        listOf(WorkStations.EXTRUDER, WorkStations.MOVEMENTS)
    ),
    Operator(
        "James",
        listOf(WorkStations.OUTSIDE)
    ),
    Operator(
        "Tall Paul",
    ),
    Operator(
        "Josh")
    )

fun areWorkStationsCovered(array: ArrayList<Operator>): Boolean {
    val newList = array.flatMap { it.workStations }.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().filter { it.value >= 1 }
    println(newList)
    return newList.size >= 4
}

println(areWorkStationsCovered(array))
```

}

returns:

```
{PANEL=2, OUTSIDE=4, MOVEMENTS=4, EXTRUDER=2}
true
```

But this isn't correct, as if Paul and Alan are off then this is returned:

```
{PANEL=1, OUTSIDE=3, MOVEMENTS=2, EXTRUDER=1}
true
```

It looks ok but its not correct as  Jack would need to do the EXTRUDER therefore only 1 movements person and Andy would have to do the PANEL therefore no Movements person, I think I need to remove people from the original list but just cant think of a simplistic, functional approach any thoughts would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I don't understand why it's not correct. What output do you expect? Please don't describe it. Post it like this: `{PANEL=1, ... }`

Comment: P1 can do A, B, C,
P2 can do A, B, C,
P3 can do B,
P4 can do C, D,
P5 can do C, D,
P6 can do B.                                          
        
    One of each (A, B, C, D) are all required but P's can do only 1 at a time i.e if P2 is removed P1 has to be A ONLY.

Comment: I got the problem. I wrote you an answer but I'm sorry without code. But the algorithm should be clear. If I have some time I edit my answer and add some code

Comment: Appreciate that kuzdu

Comment: I edit my answer and add some working code. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, each operator may perform only one workstation and each workstation must be occupied at least once.

**Surely there is a better and more performant solution. But you can always optimize in the end.**

I wrote tests and so far this should work. I had to change your data structure and your test data a little bit.

```
enum class WorkStation {
    PANEL, OUTSIDE, MOVEMENTS, EXTRUDER
}

data class Operator(
    val name: String, var workStations: MutableList<WorkStation> =
        mutableListOf()
)

data class OperatorWithWorkstation(
    val name: String, var workStation: WorkStation
)

class ExampleUnitTest {

    private val operators = arrayListOf(
        Operator(
            "Andy",
            mutableListOf(WorkStation.MOVEMENTS, WorkStation.PANEL, WorkStation.EXTRUDER)
        ),
        Operator(
            "Alan",
            mutableListOf(WorkStation.MOVEMENTS, WorkStation.OUTSIDE, WorkStation.EXTRUDER)
        ),
        Operator(
            "Matt",
            mutableListOf(WorkStation.EXTRUDER)
        ),
        Operator(
            "Paul",
            mutableListOf(WorkStation.EXTRUDER, WorkStation.MOVEMENTS)
        ),
        Operator(
            "Jack",
            mutableListOf(WorkStation.EXTRUDER, WorkStation.MOVEMENTS)
        ),
        Operator(
            "James",
            mutableListOf(WorkStation.OUTSIDE)
        ),
        Operator(
            "Tall Paul",
        ),
        Operator(
            "Josh"
        )
    )

    private val operatorsOnWorkstation = mutableListOf<OperatorWithWorkstation>()

    @Test
    fun everyWorkSpaceIsManned() {
        // WHEN
        addOperatorsToWorkstations(1)

        // THEN
        val allWorkstations = operatorsOnWorkstation.map { it.workStation }
        assertTrue(allWorkstations.count() == 4)
        assertTrue(allWorkstations.contains(WorkStation.EXTRUDER))
        assertTrue(allWorkstations.contains(WorkStation.OUTSIDE))
        assertTrue(allWorkstations.contains(WorkStation.MOVEMENTS))
        assertTrue(allWorkstations.contains(WorkStation.PANEL))
    }

    @Test
    fun notEveryWorkSpaceIsManned() {
        // GIVEN

        // remove ANDY
        operators.removeAt(0)
        // remove ALAN
        operators.removeAt(0)

        // WHEN
        addOperatorsToWorkstations(1)

        // THEN
        val allWorkstations = operatorsOnWorkstation.map { it.workStation }
        assertTrue(allWorkstations.count() == 3)
    }

    @Test
    fun checkIfAlgorithmPicksTheWorkstationClever() {
        // GIVEN
        // remove PAUL
        operators.removeAt(3)
        // remove JACK
        operators.removeAt(3)

        // WHEN
        addOperatorsToWorkstations(1)

        // THEN
        val allWorkstations = operatorsOnWorkstation.map { it.workStation }
        assertTrue(allWorkstations.count() == 4)
        assertTrue(allWorkstations.contains(WorkStation.EXTRUDER))
        assertTrue(allWorkstations.contains(WorkStation.OUTSIDE))
        assertTrue(allWorkstations.contains(WorkStation.MOVEMENTS))
        assertTrue(allWorkstations.contains(WorkStation.PANEL))
    }

    private fun addOperatorsToWorkstations(startCount: Int) {
        if (startCount > 4 || operators.isEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        val operator = findOperatorForWorkStation(startCount)

        if (operator == null) {
            addOperatorsToWorkstations(startCount + 1)
            return
        }

        operators.removeIf { it.name == operator.name }
        operatorsOnWorkstation.add(operator)
        addOperatorsToWorkstations(startCount)
    }

    private fun findOperatorForWorkStation(count: Int): OperatorWithWorkstation? {
        // start with operators which can work on less workstations
        val filteredOperators = operators.filter { it.workStations.count() == count }

        var result: OperatorWithWorkstation? = null
        val allMannedWorkstations = operatorsOnWorkstation.map { it.workStation }

        for (operator in filteredOperators) {
            // remove all workstations which already in use
            for (workstation in allMannedWorkstations) {
                operator.workStations.remove(workstation)
            }

            if (operator.workStations.isNotEmpty()) {


                // has this operator a workstations which only can solved by him
                val allPossibleWorkstations = operators.filter { it.workStations.count() >= count }
                    .flatMap { it.workStations }.distinct()

                var selectedWorkStation: WorkStation? = null
                for (workstation in operator.workStations) {
                    if (!allPossibleWorkstations.contains(workstation)) {
                        selectedWorkStation = workstation
                    }
                }

                if (selectedWorkStation == null) {
                    selectedWorkStation = operator.workStations.first()
                }

                // only the workstation where the operator is working on is added
                result = OperatorWithWorkstation(
                    name = operator.name,
                    workStation = selectedWorkStation
                )
                break
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

The idea is that you fill an array with one operator which has one workingstation.

*I know you could optimize a lot. I think the Big O Annotation is n^2 But you have to decide how much you like to optimize. And if it's needed for you case. I do the list arithmetic with for loops and remove. I think there would be possible solution with `intersect` or `subtract` as well.*